# how to convert char string into a std string

Tags: c++

I have following code and I cant figure out how to convert char string into a std string. Can someone help me out here?

```
char Path[STRING_MAX];
test->getValue(Config::CODE,Path);

size_t found;
cout << "Splitting: " << Path << endl;
found=Path.find_last_of("/");
cout << " folder: " << Path.substr(0,found) << endl;
cout << " file: " << Path.substr(found+1) << endl;
```

Comment: Please indent code 4 spaces to have it show up properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
std::string sPath(Path);
```

or:

```
std::string sPath = Path;
```

or:

```
std::string sPath;
sPath.assign(Path);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the C-string **is** null-terminated, then the approaches Erik demonstrated will work fine.

However if the C-string **is not** null-terminated, then one must do the following (assuming one knows the length of the valid data):

```
std::string sPath(Path, PathLength);
```

or:

```
// given std::string sPath
sPath.assign(Path, PathLength);
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string pathstr(Path);` will convert it using the constructor for `std::string`.